# Center of $G/Z(G)$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

***Question.*** Prove or disprove: The center of $G/Z(G)$ is trivial for all finite groups $G$. (Here $Z(G)$ denotes the center of $G$.)

***Attempt at a Proof.*** 
Assume the contrary that $G/Z(G)$ has a non-trivial center.

Let $g\notin Z(G)$ be such that $gZ(G)$ is in the center of $G/Z(G)$.

Then $$\boxed{xgx^{-1}\in gZ(G)}$$ for all $x\in G$.

We note that $xgx^{-1}=ygy^{-1}$ if and only if $xC_G(g)=yC_G(g)$, where $C_G(g)$ denotes the centralizer of $g$ in $G$.

Since $g\notin Z(G)$, we have $G\neq C_G(g)$.

I couldn't go any further.

Can someone help?

Comment: Actually it is not true so you need to consider a counterexample. HINT: If $G$ not abelian then $Z(G)$ is a proper subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Try finding a counterexample.

Comment: Well, the claim is false, so no wonder you couldn't go on...Try any $\;p$-group, say of order $\;8\;$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know this result? $$G/Z(G) \cong \operatorname{Inn}(G)$$

You may want to look at $S_n$.

---

Edit: It fails for $n=6$, but it's not easy to see why $\{e\} <\operatorname{Inn}(S_6) < \operatorname{Aut}(S_6)$. But $S_6$ is a good counter-example.

To study more about $S_6$ and why $\{e\} < \operatorname{Inn}(S_6) < \operatorname{Aut}(S_6)$ read this wikipedia [entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_automorphism_of_S_6#The_exceptional_outer_automorphism_of_S6).

Comment: Well, what you propose seems not to be a good example, as $\;Z(S_3)=1\implies S_3/Z(S_3)=S_3\;$ and thus the quotient's center is, again, trivial...

Answer (score 7):

Not only the statement that ”$G/Z(G)$ is trivial” is false, but a very important class of groups is defined by means of “repeated centers”. Let $G$ be a group and define
$$
Z_0(G)=\{1\},\qquad
Z_{k+1}(G)/Z_k(G)=Z(G/Z_{k}(G))\text{ for $k\ge0$}.
$$
In other words, $Z_{k+1}(G)$ is the inverse image of $Z(G/Z_{k}(G))$ under the canonical projection $G\to G/Z_{k}(G)$.

A group is called *nilpotent* if there is a $k$ such that $Z_k(G)=G$.

Nilpotent groups are abundant: for instance, every finite $p$-group is nilpotent because of the following lemma, whose easiest proof relies on the study of conjugacy classes.

**Lemma.** *Every finite $p$-group $G\ne\{1\}$ has nontrivial center.*

Answer (score 5):

Recall that if $G$ is a non-abelian group of order $p^3$, then $\overline G=G/Z(G)\simeq C_p\times C_p$. Then $Z(\overline G)=\overline G$ will be nontrivial.

Answer (score 4):

Consider $D_4$ (dihedral group or the symmetry group of a square). It has 8 elements and can be represented as a permutation group on vertices $\{1,2,3,4\}$ of a square as follows:

- $(1,2,3,4),(1,3)(2,4),(1,4,3,2),(1)(2)(3)(4)$ - rotations;
- $(2,4)(1)(3),(1,3)(2)(4),(1,2)(3,4),(1,4)(2,3)$ - symmetries.

So, $Z(D_4)=\{(1,3)(2,4),(1)(2)(3)(4)\}$ of order 2. Thus $|D_4/Z(D_4)|=4$ and the factor-group is Abelian (as all groups of order less then 6).